# Big Query cache

Tags: sql, caching, google-bigquery

I have three questions related to [BigQuery's cache](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#query-caching), as the ability to get results from cache greatly reduces costs on large queries.

1. If the data has not been modified, is there a way to extend the cache longer than the default of ~24 hours. For example, what if I have a static dataset that hasn't been changed in 6 months?
2. Is there a way to retrieve results from cache if there have been subtle changes on the query that doesn't affect what information it is retrieving? For example:

   - `SELECT first_name, last_name FROM mytable` vs `SELECT last_name, first_name FROM mytable` (ordering)
   - `SELECT id, last_name FROM mytable` vs `SELECT id, last_name AS last, FROM mytable` (alias)
   - `select id from table` vs `SELECT id FROM table` (caps)
3. Is cache automatically invalidated if the data-set is modified? If not, is there a way to manually invalidate all cache for that table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- 1 - there is no way to make cache leave longer than 24 hours, rather than copy it to permanent table and then use it. Usually result much lower in size than original table so this can work for you. Also have in mind that if your data is not changing for 90 days - the cost of its storing gets reduced 50% - so called [long term storage](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#long-term-storage)
- 2 - yes. thechnically speaking you can use that temp (anonymous) table as a regular table and query it. It is not officially supported though!! Yo can find fully qualified path in respective job info
- 3 - it is!

Comment: thanks! how do they determine when to return a cached query set then? Is it a checksum of the input string of the query? or something else?

Comment: @David542 - main criteria - your query must be identical and underlying data didn't changed since last query. there are more in here - details are in link you used in your question

Comment: right, I guess my question then is for the statement: "`statistics.query.cacheHit returns as true`", what conditions need to be met for it to return `true` ?

Comment: @David542 - whatever I mentioned above  - plus you need to make sure useQueryCache property set to true. BUT - there are number of exceptions  - you can see them here - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#query-caching